# getting username and tweets about depression

Tags: twitter, dataset

I am collecting Data from twitter for data analysis.i need a collection of tweet contains "#depression" tag for make a dataset . it is very difficult to go to search then copy and paste. 
if there are any existing code/plugin/api to get all post with username and post date? i will use it to store post,username,date on my excel dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a bit of python for this. Incidently, here seems to be a script that does something like what you want. It will get all tweets from a specified date, with a specified #tag - and print them to a CSV file. I guess you could import the file in Excel.

The script:
https://gist.github.com/vickyqian/f70e9ab3910c7c290d9d715491cde44c

I have not read it thoroughly - so read through it before invkoking. And of course replace the #tag parameter:

```
...
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#depression",count=100,
...
```

You also need to to set  up the parameters:

```
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''
```

Here's the instructions on how to get those:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/access-tokens.html

And you need to specify the fields that you are requiring in this line

```
print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
```

These fields are available:

```
text     = tweet.text
language = tweet.lang
date     = tweet.created_at
username = tweet.user
retweets = tweet.retweet_count
likes    = tweet.favorite_count
```

So you could change it to this:

```
print (tweet.created_at, tweet.user, tweet.text)
```